# Need help in n tree implementation

Tags: c#, recursion, tree, mutation

I am trying to implement n-ary kind of data structure using c #. The tree will have a root node and array of children and each child in the children array will also have set of children node. What I am trying to do is whenever we add children array that should be added to all the child present in the leaf node. my code is

```
      public void addChildren(Node root, Node[] children)
        {

             if (root.children == null)
            {
                root.children = children;

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < root.children.Length; i++)
                {

                    addChildren(root.children[i], children);
                }
            }

        }
```

> **Main program**

```
     Dictionary<String, String[]> measurelist = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
        String[] values = { "y", "n" };
        measurelist.Add("m1", values);
        measurelist.Add("m2", values);
        measurelist.Add("m3", values);           
        foreach (KeyValuePair<String, String[]> entry in measurelist)
        {
            Node[] children = new Node[entry.Value.Length];
           for(int i = 0; i < entry.Value.Length ;i ++)
            {
                Node child = new Node(entry.Key+":"+entry.Value[i]);
                children[i] = child;
            }

            clustertree.addChildren(clustertree.root, children);               
        }
```

but this code results in infinite recursive calls. I tried but unable to figure out what is going wrong? Please help me to find out what I am doing wrong.
[I have described the problem in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVtKN.png)

> **Solution:**
>   With the help of you I have found the solution to this issue. If I explain the root cause I think it will be helpful for others who may face the same issue.
>   The main cause of the issue when I am passing the children array of nodes it is passed as a reference not by values. I have changed my code a little in order to make sure that the same  children array reference is not passed to the next recursion call.
>
> **Here is my corrected code**:

```
 public void addChildren(Node root, Node[] children)
        {

             if (root.children == null)
            {

                root.children = children;

            }
            else
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < root.children.Length; i++)
                {                       
                    Node[] children1 = new Node[children.Length];
          //I am creating a new array and nodes and passing the newly created array to                                       the next recursive call
                    for (int j = 0; j < children.Length; j++)
                    {
                        Node node = new Node(children[j].key);                           
                        node.children = children[j].children;
                        children1[j] = node;
                    }
                    addChildren(root.children[i], children1);
                }
            }

        }
```

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not creating the tree as you've shown in diagram, rather you're doing something like below:

```
       R
      / \
     /   \
    a1   a2 (children of this are actually b1 and b2)
   / \   
  /   \
 b1   b2
```

When you add the `b1, b2` as children of `a2` you're referencing to the same `b1 and b2` that have been alreayd added to `a1`.

In next iteration when you add `c1 and c2`, according to your algorithm you reference `c1 and c2` to both `b1 and b2` firstly via `a1` but your function does not stop here, it goes again to `b1 and b2` this time via `a2`, but since `c1 and c2` have been already added as children of `b1 and b2`, the algorithm gets confuse and goes into forever loop.

To solve this problem:

Find the last level of tree but till last level only use recursive path using one child only.

```
public boolean addChildren(Node root, Node[] children)
{

    if (root.children == null)
    {
        root.children = children;
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < root.children.Length; i++)
        {
            /* if it returns true then it was last level 
                   else break */
            if(!addChildren(root.children[i], children)) 
            {
                /* this is non-last level break */
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should probably make your internal `node[]` into a `list<node>` instead of an array.

Then use this code

```
      public void addChildren(Node root, Node[] children)
        {

            if (root.children == null)
            {
                root.children = new List<Node>();

            }

            root.children.AddRange(children);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.If I use your code I am getting a tree having a root having four children. But I need a tree having a root with two children and each children with again two children. In the above scenario i want root -> m1:y,m1:n and m1:y ->m2:y,m2:n ,m1:n -> m2:y,m2:n and so on

Comment: apologies you hadn't added your main program when I posted my answer